# Model selection for and forecasting of arctic oscillation (a seasonal time series)

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, seasonality

I'm having a doubt with a time series. I have to find the best model for it and use it to do some forecast. The data are about the arctic oscillation (AO) from 1950 to 2015.

[image: Plot of the ts]

The series is clearly stationary, and the augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) test confirms it.

The ACF and PACF for absolute values of the series are depicted below.

[image]

Running `seasonplot` from "forecast" package in R, I can see that in the summer months the values look clearly more clustered, while during the end/beginning of the year the values are more scattered.

The question is: How can I find the best model? Based on the PACF, before seeing the seasonality, I chose an AR(1), and it was good till I discovered the seasonal thing. How can I find the best model to do forecasting?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you *see* seasonality?

Comment: Without the reputation I cannot post a seasonalplot! :D I see it doing the absolute value of the ACF and PACF, the movement is pretty clear

Comment: You could perhaps try function `auto.arima` from "forecast" package in R. Do not forget to allow for seasonality.

Comment: Already did, the output is:

ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept
      0.3064    -0.1159
s.e.  0.0338     0.0491

sigma^2 estimated as 0.9202:  log likelihood=-1090.9
AIC=2187.8   AICc=2187.83   BIC=2201.82

But the ACF and PACF of the residuals are still out of the interval confidence and they still have the typical seasonal wave form, they oscillate under and over the 0 line

Comment: Have you specified that your series has a frequency of 12? If you forgot that, `auto.arima` will not consider seasonality. Also, what do you mean by  "doing" in "Doing the absolute value of both ACF and PACF..."?

Comment: I see two options. One is to run ARIMA()S(12), basically, to impose seasonility 12 lags based on physics. The second is to remove the seasonality using Census Bureau's X13 utility, then work with deseasonalized series.

Comment: @RichardHardy I tried this: try=auto.arima(clima.ts,stationary=TRUE,ic="aic",trace = TRUE). With "Doing..." I mean Acf(abs(mydata)). (thanks for the corrections!)

Comment: @Aksakal I tried a SARIMA like this: prova2=sarima(clima.ts,1,0,0,0,0,0,12), am I right? The AIC is really close to the one from the auto.arima above, that is an AR(1). Is there a way to judge which one is the best?

Comment: What do you mean by "close"? You need a sense of scale to judge the closeness. if AIC is your criterion then you go with it. I have other criteria when selecting the model, including out-of-sample testing and a bunch of diagnostics

Comment: It is important that `clima.ts` is a `ts` object with frequency 12. You can do that by taking a vector `clima` and applying function `ts` like `clima.ts = ts(data = clima, start = c(1950,1), frequency = 12)`.

Comment: @Aksakal The Census Bureau's X13 isn't the right choice for me, it works only with non negative values, not my case. The AIC that I get from the AR(1) with non-zero mean is AIC=2187.8. Doing the SARIMA I get AIC=2187.8. It's exactly the same! Everything is the same, coefficients, log likehood, AIC, sigma^2. What should I get from it?

Comment: @RichardHardy That's exactly what it is Richard: clima.ts=ts(clima[[1]],start=c(1950,1),frequency=12)

Comment: Could you post your data?

Comment: You have too much noise, I suppose, which hides seasonality. Don't use seasonality if you can't estimate it well then.

Comment: Here they are: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/gcos_wgsp/Timeseries/Data/ao.dat

Comment: Everything was fine till my teacher found the seasonality in the residuals. He suggested to make a ugarch model, doing a ugarchspec with garchOrder=c(12,12) and then work with the alphas and betas. Then put them to 0 in fixed.pars if they're not significant. What do you think about that?

Comment: After running `auto.arima` with default settings, I got ARIMA(2,1,1) with relatively nice residual ACF and PACF. The AIC is much lower than in your case: it is `1801.23` in mine. I wonder why you got different results. Did you use some non-default settings in `auto.arima`? Also, a GARCH(12,12) model would be an overkill, IMHO (unless you have a good argument for that like the ARCH-LM test result and perhaps some subject-matter considerations).

Comment: I think my graph of the data does not quite match yours. One of us got it wrong (perhaps me). I will give it a rest for today.

Comment: What a strange thing! Running the auto.arima with default settings I get ARIMA(1,1,1)(1,0,2)[12], with the AIC=2188.49. How is that possible? All I do is: try=auto.arima(clima.ts)!

Comment: @RichardHardy There is a more recent version of the data, it is this one: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/gcos_wgsp/Timeseries/Data/ao.long.data 
Thank you Richard, have a nice rest!

Comment: please post the data in a single column format ....

Comment: @IrishStat These are the data as I've got them: http://textuploader.com/525dv

Comment: @Limbs, my bad, the comparison of AIC values between your model and my model (as in a comment above) does not make sense since my model uses differenced data while yours uses non-differenced data. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a seasonal ARIMA model could offer a sensible approximation to the process, you could try using function `auto.arima` from the "forecast" package in R. It will first select the order of integration (by default using the KPSS test, optionally using augmented Dickey-Fuller or Phillips-Perron unit root tests) and seasonal integration (by default using OCSB test, optionally using Canova-Hansen test). Then it will select the SARIMA order based on the an information criterion (by default using AICc, optionally using AIC or BIC) from a pool of models defined by a local search procedure explained in Hyndman & Khandakar (2008).

Regarding seasonality: when dealing with seasonal data, make sure to supply a seasonal time series (e.g. a `ts` object with a specified frequency which is 12 for monthly data) to `auto.arima`. Seasonal integration will be determined by testing (OCSB or Canova-Hansen), while seasonal AR and MA components will be determined by minimization of an information criterion. Since it makes sense to use AIC for model selection when the goal is forecasting (see e.g. Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["Facts and fallacies of the AIC"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/aic/)), you may not worry too much if no seasonal part is selected but model residuals show mild patterns of remaining seasonality; AIC should select some seasonal components if the seasonality can be estimated precisely enough to improve forecasting but would leave them out if that cannot be done (so that inclusion of the seasonal components could do more harm through increased model variance than they help through reduced model bias).

Also note that the values of information criteria are not comparable between non-differenced and differenced data (again, see Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["Facts and fallacies of the AIC"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/aic/)), so you cannot use, say, AIC to compare between ARIMA(1,0,0) and ARIMA(0,1,0).

**References:**

- Hyndman, Rob J., and Yeasmin Khandakar. *Automatic time series for forecasting: the forecast package for R*. No. 6/07. Monash University, Department of Econometrics and Business Statistics, 2007.

Comment: Thank you Richard! You've been very clear and insightful with your explanation, I couldn't have asked for a better answer. Cheers, Marco

Comment: I am happy I could help! Please be aware that the note of caution hiding in my first line may be of real concern. The SARIMA model need not necessarily be a reasonably good approximation (I don't know the specifics of arctic oscillations, so I will not try evaluating that from the subject-matter perspective, but you may look at the model residuals and see if they are free from ugly patterns) and there may be more suitable models out there.